# Multiple Server Indexing - Isolate Indexing Process

Tags: magento-1.7, indexing, indexer

We run a multi-server magento install. 2 webservers, 1 MySQL server and 1 server for the magento admin. When I am running an indexing process via the command line using the admin server I am noticing that the indexing queries are being sent by our other 2 webservers in addition to the admin server. This is creating a real high load and takes a long time for the index to complete.

I have removed all the lock files from var/locks and it does not seem to make a difference.

any suggestions on how to isolate the indexing process to the single admin server?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that the web servers are trying to perform the same reindex?

Comment: I concluded that the indexing commands were being issued by multiple servers via the Show Processes command from the mysql command prompt on the MySQL server.

The Magento server setup is pretty basic, 2 webservers behind a load balancer that are syncronized,  1 admin server pointing to the 1 MySQL server.

Indexing process is initiated from the CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reindexing via CLI, then it has no bearing on the web application itself, nor your web server's PHP process.

It sounds much more likely that neither web node is trying to complete the reindex on behalf of the CLI command (thats improbable) but rather that it is trying to complete a single product reindex (either from a product save, or checkout observer)